# Add a calendar event using a webpage button via webview

Tags: java, android

I want to use a webview to pull up a page and on it is a label of an event and a button that says add to calendar. When pushed it will add the details of the event to the google cal on the android phone.

I am attempting to use content values but with no luck as of yet. This is what I have but I am open for suggestions.  I think I have read every post on stackoverflow concerning this so I am looking for something new or more complete than whats been posted already.

```
public class button7 extends Activity{

 WebView wb = null;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.buttons);
  wb = new WebView(this);
  wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
  wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  wb.loadUrl("http://whatever website.com");
  setContentView(wb);
 }

 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
   view.loadUrl(url);
   SetCalenderEntry(1,"Test","Is this working","At home");
   return true;
  }

 }




 private void SetCalenderEntry(int i,  String subject, String body, String location) 
 {
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put("calendar_id", i);
    event.put("title", subject);
    event.put("description", body);
    event.put("eventLocation", location);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60;
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2;
    event.put("dtstart", startTime);
    event.put("dtend", endTime);
    Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
 }

 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && wb.canGoBack())
   wb.goBack();
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/) if you are trying to manipulate the user's Google Calendar.

Comment: Well as stated in my request I have read that and it includes no examples. I don't under stand how to translate that to android.  So if there are any tutorials or examples specific to android that would be awesome.

Comment: @Sabanim: There's a whole presentation on using Google GData APIs from the 2011 Google I|O conference.

Comment: Further information can be found in my reply to your cross-post to the `android-developers` Google Group: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/d8fc5e309cede29e